# Firebase Storage uploading csv file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Ive created a WebApp via Firebase to Upload files to Cloud storage, however as i choose the file to upload, there is no action, the choose file action doesn't upload the file.

i've checked the following:

- Storage rules: they are open
- Browser settings: same issue across all browsers.

below is a my index.html file and hopefuly anyone can shed some slight on this strange issue?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Upload App</title>
  <style media="screen">
    body {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    #uploader {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 50%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
  <input type="file" value="upload" id="fileButton" />

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCA7XWfS7deQaYGgaUaTWK-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "testapp.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://test-project.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "testproject",
      storageBucket: "testbucket_inbound/mydata/",
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    //Get Elements
    var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
    var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

    //Listen for file selection
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      // Get file
      var file = e.target.files[0];

      // Create storage ref
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('mydata/' + file.name);

      // upload file
      var task = storageRef.put(file);

      // update progress bar
      task.on('state_changed',

        function progress(snapshot) {
          var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred /
            snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          uploader.value = percentage;
        },

        function error(err) {

        },

        function complete() {

        }

      );
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI, I've tested your code and it works perfectly. Note that i have experimented that for Cloud Storage you may have to wait few seconds before a change in the security rules is applied

Comment: There is no "deployment" as such: I just copied-pasted your code in an local HTML page and modified the `config` object with the values of one of my test project and then I opened the page with a browser and tried: the uploaded files are correctly saved to Firebase Storage.

Comment: ok thanks,  this is the issue i'm having go to this url: https://gymwin-199801.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Your process seems ok. What I have tried is just an HTML page stored on my hard disk. You don't necessarily need to deploy your page to the hosting service of Firebase in order to "run" it. But if you deploy it, it should behave the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the page you have deployed:

you declare your button as follow in your HTML

```
<input type="file" value="upload" id="filebutton" />
```

but you set your EventListener on a button with an id with a uppercase B

```
fileButton.addEventListener('change' , function(e) {
```

Change to

```
filebutton.addEventListener('change' , function(e) {
```

and it should work.

You can see the error from the browser Console: `ReferenceError: fileButton is not defined`

Finally note that in the code of your question it is correct! You use `fileButton` at the two places.

Comment: Great!, i missed that, thanks. working now!, much appreciated